# Find the least value $a$ such that this equation is greater than or equal to zero

Tags: calculus

Find the least number $a$ such that 
$x^4+ax^3+2017x^2-360x+16 \ge0$ for all positive $x$.

I tried to solve this by differentiating but it is too complicated. 
Is there good way to solve?

Comment: This seems complicated as is ... may I do what you know so far? In terms of mathematics ? (calc 1, calc 2 ..?

Comment: i tried to find a local min and local maximum but it is to difficult.

Comment: @user122794 -- It's unethical (and you surely know it!) to post problems from an online entrance exam where the cutoff date for submission is January 20, 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality can be written:

$f(x)=(x^2+45x-4)^2+(a-90)x^3\ge 0$

$x^2+45x-4=0$ has two solutions: $x_0\approx -45.089<0$ and $x_1\approx 0.088714>0$

In order to have $f(x_1)\ge 0$ one needs $a\ge 90$

We notice that $a\ge 90$ is also a sufficient condition for $f(x)\ge0$ when $x$ is positive.

So the least value $a$ is $90$

Comment: How did you find that rearrangement of the equation?

Comment: I brute-forced $\min a=90$ numerically. Then I looked for special properties of the polynomial for $a=90$, and everything fell in place.

Comment: wow thanks alot!